# How to get a new random number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript and I'm sure this question has been answered quite a bit, but when I search my question I don't seem to find an answer (or one that I actually understand :D)

Currently, I'm trying to create a tool to help kids with there multiplication facts and I'm having trouble getting the program to generate new random numbers.

```
var r1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
var r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);

function start() {
    println("Welcome to the multipilcation helper! ");
    var num = readLine("Pick a number you want to practice or type 'random'!");
    var ques = readLine("How many questions do you want?");
    if (num == "random") {

        for (var i = 0; i < ques; i++) {

            var answer = r1 * r2;
            println(r1 + "*" + r2);
            var check = readLine("what is the answer");

            if (check == answer) {
                println("thats correct!");
            } else {
                println("thats wrong! ");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that my variables seem to pick a random number as soon as the script starts and stick with it instead of giving me a new random number.

Can anyone help me out and tell me how to get a new random number every time the variable is called?

Comment: So in the loop, you want constantly new random values for `r1` and `r2`? Wouldn't it then make sense to generate the random numbers in the loop instead?

Comment: _“every time the variable is called”_ —a variable _isn’t called_. Your variables are set _once_, then never updated again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create yourself a method like the one below and use it like `r()` to get a new random number every call.

```js
function r() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
}

console.log(r());
console.log(r());
console.log(r());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function start() {
    console.log("Welcome to the multipilcation helper! ");
    var num = prompt("Pick a number you want to practice or type 'random'!");
    var ques = prompt("How many questions do you want?");
    if (num == "random") {

        for (var i = 0; i < ques; i++) {
            var r1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
            var r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
            var answer = r1 * r2;
            console.log(r1 + "*" + r2);
            var check = prompt("what is the answer");

            if (check == answer) {
                console.log("thats correct!");
            } else {
                console.log("thats wrong! ");
            }

        }
    }
}

start()
```

You random numbers are being static at the moment. They need to be called again. Move your `r1` and `r2` assignments inside the `for`.

> I don't have enough reputation to comment, but will update the answer
>   if you explain it with more details.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you should be reassigning the random numbers so that they are reassigned every iteration of the loop. Otherwise they stay static to the value you give them at the top.

Also, you should use triple equals in Javascript when checking for equality as it is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the random call in a function in order for it to create a new number each time. When you assign it directly to a variable as you have, it only runs once and stores that value in the variable.

```js
// pick a number between 0 and 13
var random = function() {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
}

function start(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
      // call random function for each number and store in a var
      var number1 = random();
      var number2 = random();
      var answer = number1 * number2;
      console.log('equation:', number1 + '*' + number2);
      console.log('answer:', answer);

    }
}

// call the start function
start()
```